# How find this $\frac{1}{x-y}+\frac{1}{y-z}+\frac{1}{x-z}$ minimum of the value

Tags: inequality

let $x,y,z\in R$,and such $x>y>z$,and such
$$(x-y)(y-z)(x-z)=16$$
find this follow minimum of the value
$$I=\dfrac{1}{x-y}+\dfrac{1}{y-z}+\dfrac{1}{x-z}$$

My  idea: since
$$\dfrac{1}{x-y}+\dfrac{1}{y-z}+\dfrac{1}{x-z}=\dfrac{x-z}{(x-y)(y-z)}+\dfrac{1}{x-z}$$
so
$$I=\dfrac{(x-z)^2}{16}+\dfrac{1}{x-z}=\dfrac{(x-z)^2}{16}+\dfrac{1}{2(x-z)}+\dfrac{1}{2(x-z)}\ge\dfrac{3}{4}$$

if and only if $(x-z)=2$,so $(x-y)(y-z)=8$
But we know $$(x-z)^2=[[(x-y)+(y-z)]^2\ge 4(x-y)(y-z)$$
so  this is wrong,

Now  I let $x-z=t$ it is clear $t\ge 4$,so
$$\dfrac{t^2}{16}+\frac{1}{t}=f(t)\Longrightarrow f'(t)\ge 0,t\ge 4$$
so
$$f(t)\ge f(4)=\dfrac{5}{4}$$

My Question: I fell my  methods is ugly,I think this problem have other simple methods.Thank you

Comment: You can rephrase it as: Minimize $\frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{b}+\frac{1}{c}$ for real $a,b,c$ so that $abc=16$ and $a+b+c=0$.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews, It should be $$a+b-c=0$$

Comment: Whoops, yes, missed the sign difference. @lab

Answer (score 5):

Let $\displaystyle a=x-y,b=y-z, c=x-z\implies abc=16$ and $\displaystyle a+b-c=0\iff c=a+b$

$$\frac1a+\frac1b+\frac1c=\frac{ab+bc+ca}{abc}=\dfrac{\dfrac{16}c+c(a+b)}{16}=\dfrac{\dfrac{16}c+c(c)}{16}$$

Now use [Second Derivative Test](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SecondDerivativeTest.html)

Comment: It's simple than me! Thank you +1

Comment: @shadow That's because $c=2 \implies a+b=2, ab = 8$ which has no solution in real numbers!  This answer is NOT correct.

Comment: Can you finish the solution and find the $x, y, z$?

Comment: @lab bhattacharjee As pointed out in the solution, I think you need to include the condition that $c\ge4$.

Comment: @user84413, I think that should be dictated by the $2$nd derivative test

Comment: Yup, I see that, sorry about that. Unnecessary comment deleted.

Comment: @shadow10 I'm sorry, but I don't see how to get $c=4$ using the 2nd derivative test.  Isn't $c=2$ the only critical point?

Answer (score 1):

You have reached
$$I = \frac{(x-z)^2}{16}+\frac1{x-z} = \frac{(x-z)^2}{16}+\frac4{x-z}+\frac4{x-z}-\frac7{x-z} \ge 3-\frac7{x-z} \ge \frac54$$
The last inequality is because $$x-z = \frac{16}{(x-y)(y-z)} \ge \frac{64}{(x-z)^2} \implies x-z \ge 4$$

---

P.S. Equality is when $x-y = y - z = 2$

Answer (score 0):

First, let $ a=x-y $, $b=y-z$, and $c=x-z$. Then, note that $ a + b - c = 0 $; i.e. $c=a+b$ and $a,b,c>0$. Finally, $abc=16$; i.e. $ab(a+b)=16$. Then, $$ I = \frac {1}{a} + \frac {1}{b} + \frac {1}{a+b}. $$You can either finish like **lab bhattacharjee** did, or you can use the method of [Lagrange Multipliers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_multiplier). I will post the Lagrange solution. Note that $$ \nabla I = \left< - \frac {1}{a^2} - \frac {1}{(a+b)^2}, - \frac {1}{b^2} - \frac {1}{(a+b)^2} \right> $$and $$ \nabla \left( \text{constraint} \right) = \nabla \left( ab(a+b) \right) = \left< b(2a+b), a(a+2b) \right>. $$Now, these two gradients must be proportional, so we get $$ \frac {b(2a+b)}{\frac{1}{a^2} + \frac {1}{(a+b)^2}} = \frac {a(a+2b)}{\frac{1}{b^2} + \frac {1}{(a+b)^2}}. $$Doing some algebra yields $ a = b $ when $a,b>0$. Hence, $c=a+b=2a$, so $$ abc = a \cdot a \cdot \left( 2a \right) = 16 \iff a = 2, $$ giving $ b = 2 $ and $ c = 4 $, and the minimum value of $I$ is, therefore, $$ \frac {1}{a} + \frac {1}{b} + \frac {1}{c} = \frac {1}{2} + \frac {1}{2} + \frac {1}{4} = \boxed {\dfrac {5}{4}}. $$